Use Dependency of Dependency in Maven
Our code base has several projects in it, and many of them share similar or identical dependencies, specifically Spring Boot and several Jakarta libraries, ex:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${env.PROJECT_LIBRARIES}\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

(Unfortunately due to system restrictions, we have to import the JARs from a local repository instead of the general Maven repository)
We also have a secondary Commons project that compiles to a JAR and is imported to the others, and I was wondering if there was a way to include the Maven dependencies there and utilize them through that directory
I tried including the dependencies in the Commons project and removing them from the dependency list of the parent, but it causes the parent to fail to compile, as the required libraries cannot be found

You can install dependency to local repository manually.

Unfortunately due to system restrictions, we have to import the JARs from a local repository instead of the general Maven repository that does not make sense... it's contradicting the idea of using a build tool which manages the dependencies. Use a repository manager that will solve a lot of issues...

Have you considered setting up a maven repository manager (like artifactory or nexus) in the network you are working on which is populated by some means with the dependencies that you need? This way you could work with that repo instead of the general maven one?

@khmarbaise I'll be honest, I don't fully understand how to set up dependencies as a whole; when I came onto this project, it was done by putting all of the JAR files in a Libraries folder on the code repository, then configuring the Maven POM to copy those into the WAR for the project to be deployed out to a Tomcat server. If there's a better way to do this, I'd be more than happy to look into it. Edit: The reason we can't connect to the Maven repository is because our network blocks all connection attempts we've tried, so downloading JARs directly was a workaround

@NathanS If you would need to set this up for only your team and also maintain it than it's probably not worth it. But based on what you have written another option would be to talk to the network admins to resolve your issues with downloads from the public maven repos.

@khmarbaise maven is not only about dependency management. And even if you don't use that feature of maven now there is still the possibility to introduce it in future.

@SpaceTrucker Unfortunately those system admins are well outside of our chain of command, so that's not an option. Related, I've seen some recommendations of putting the JAR files in the Tomcat libraries directly and changing the Maven scope from System to Provided; do you think that would be a better option? It would save us from having the same set of JARs copied across all of our projects, at least

Let's separate 2 issues: 1. how to manage dependencies with no public internet access and 2. moving dependency to common lib. For the former you can use: a) local repository (but you are doing it completely wrong, you are misusing a deprecated feature, you need to declare a <repository> pointing to a dir where artifacts are stored in maven layout. b) artifact manager like nexus in local network, as already advised by @SpaceTrucker. For the second problem - moving a dependency to a shared lib - maven resolves deps transitively, even with system scope - reproducible example would help.

Just tell your boss that you need a Nexus or Artifactory server and that he/she should talk to the system admins and/or upper management about it.
